# could not install package Facebook 6.4.2

Tags: windows-phone-8, facebook-c#-sdk, nuget-package

I'm trying to install facebook C# sdk from **NuGet Console** into my **windows phone 8** app, **.NET framework 4.0**
But it's giving an error! Details is give below :

```
PM> Install-Package Facebook
Successfully installed 'Facebook 6.4.2'.
Successfully uninstalled 'Facebook 6.4.2'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Install-Package : Could not install package 'Facebook 6.4.2'. You are trying to install this package into a project that 
targets 'WindowsPhone,Version=v8.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Facebook
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

If i try to install this **Install-Package Facebook.Client -pre** then also I get the same error !!Can anyone help me out ? Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your nuget package manager is not updated. Please update your nuget manager, restart and then try again. It should work fine.