# Install-Package Facebook giving error

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-8.1, nuget

I am using Visual studio 2013 update 5,windows phone 8.1.

I am trying to install NuGet package but it gives me this error

```
PM> Install-Package Facebook  
Install-Package : Unable to find package 'Facebook'.  
At line:1 char:1  
+ Install-Package Facebook  
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand  
PM>
```

I have updated the visual studio and also the nuget package manager.
Have tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072546/could-not-install-package-facebook-6-4-2) but this doesn't solved my problem.

Comment: what kind of project are you using?

Comment: Actually i am developing an app on windows phone 8.1 ,the app will integrate with facebook and will show the related data from facebook.Currently i am trying to setup the things in a sample project. I have added a blank windows phone project and tried to install package there but could not resolve my problem

Comment: Are you able to add this if you create a WindowsForm app for example? Are you behind a proxy or something like that?

Comment: No i can add all other packages without any problem , whether they are on windowsForm or windowsphone ,but its giving error for this package.

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072546/could-not-install-package-facebook-6-4-2